# OR-Tool - What is objectiveValue of Assignment model

Tags: or-tools

in this [example](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/vrptw#program) the `printSolution` has the log:

```java
logger.info("Objective : " + solution.objectiveValue());
```

So what does it mean the objectiveValue? how it is affect to solution found? also how to edit that value? the log output the number but i dont understand 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, it will be the sum of arc cost used by the fleet.
This is the value, the routing solver will try to minimize as much as possible.

You should take a look at https://groups.google.com/g/or-tools-discuss/c/YCUNTmWr8Us/m/tA1OlIfVAQAJ to know how you can add more "value" to this objective.